# Code igniter form - passing post data and populating fields from database

Tags: database, forms, codeigniter, view

I'm trying to understand how php works but I have problems with understanding syntax and arrays/objects.

1. I know that code igniter uses $_POST only and keeps form data in an array but how to access it in a view?

I have some more questions in the comments inside below code:

I understand the concept of MVC but below code is all-in-one.

```
<?php
//database - formvalidation 
//controller - form
//model - form
//model methods - add
//view form/add.php
class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model( 'Form_model' );
        $this->load->library( array( 'form_validation' ) );
    }
//controller > add
    public function add() {

        if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {     //displaying form if validation doesn't run
            $this->load->view( 'form/add' );
        }
        else {      //inserting data from the form into the database

            //I dont understand what happens here and how to access keys in the view :/
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post( 'username' ),
            );
            $this->Form_model->add( $data ); // passing data array to the view
            $this->load->view( 'form/success' ); //loading success page
        }
    }

//Form model > add
        var $table = 'formvalidation';
        public function add( $data ) {
        $this->db->insert( $this->table, $data );
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

//Form model > get all items
//how can I use this function to display data in the view?
    public function get_all() {
        return $this->db->get( $this->table )->result_array();
    }   
}
?>

    <? //view ?>

    <?php echo form_open('form/add',array('class'=>'pure-form', 'style'=>'width:50%')); ?>

<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>

    <?php foreach($asd as $a){ 
//What if I don't want to use foreach loop?
//How can i display field values in the view?
?>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $asd ?>" class="w3-input" />


    <?php } ?>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

<? //Can you show me simple example of using objects and arrays to display data in the view? ?>
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If validation fails you want to repopulate the fields with the post data so that the user doesn't have to re-enter data for inputs that didn't fail.

You can do this by using the `set_value($fieldname)` method in the form view.

```
<?php echo form_open('form/add',array('class'=>'pure-form', 'style'=>'width:50%')); ?>
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" class="w3-input" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now if a validation error occurs whatever the user posted will appear in the `username` field.

---

In this function:

```
public function get_all() {
    return $this->db->get( $this->table )->result_array();
}
```

You are using `result_array()`. `result_array()` is different than `row_array()` in that all the users in the table will be returned as an array (as long as you don't have a unique where condition) e.g. `array( 0 => array('username'=>'bob'), 1 => array('username'=>'jeff'));`. Thus you can generate a table or whatever of all of the users:

In controller: `$this->load->view('form/success', array('users' => $this->form_model->get_all());`

In view:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user['username'];
}
```

Echos: bob jeff

But I think you want to just get the user you just added... In which case a model function like this will work nicely:

```
public function get_one($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->get( $this->table )->row_array();
}
```

And then in controller:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('form/add');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        );
        $id = $this->Form_model->add($data);
        $user = $this->Form_model->get_one($id);
        $this->load->view('form/success', array('user' => $user));
    }
```

and in view:

```
echo $user['username'];
```

---

Objects generated from `result()` and `row()` are the same as their counterparts `result_array()` and `row_array()`, respectively, with the exception that objects are accessed via `->` rather than `[$somekey]`. In the last example had you passed an object by using `row()` instead of `row_array()` in `get_one()` you would access it in the view like: `$user->username;`. Assigning data to the view is usually handled in the above method, but for more info you can [view the docs.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was confusing post values with database functions values. Now that subject is a little bit brighter to me. Look below:

I didn't know where to find the information in the user guide :/

```
<?php
defined( 'BASEPATH' )OR exit( 'No direct script access allowed' );

class Lol extends CI_Controller {

function __Construct() {
    parent::__Construct();
    //loading helpers, models, libraries
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper( array( 'form' ) );
    $this->load->library( array( 'form_validation' ) );
}
//form remembers the username field value
public
function index() {
    echo form_open( 'lol' );
    $val = set_value('username');
    echo form_input( 'username', $val );
    echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit' );
    echo form_close();
}

public
function validation() {
    //setting up the form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[3]' );

    //displaying form if validation doesn't run
    if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
        echo form_error( 'username' );
        echo form_open( 'lol/validation' );
        $val = set_value('username');
        echo form_input( 'username', $val );
        echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit' );
        echo form_close();
    }
    //inserting data from the form into the database
    else {
        echo "username is ok";
    }
}
//getting field value from database in two ways: array and object. Your pick.
public
function database() {
    echo form_open( 'lol' );
    $val = $this->get_all();
    //echo form_input( 'username', $val->username ); // object
    echo form_input( 'username', $val['username'] ); //array
    echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit' );
    echo form_close();
}
//getting database data
public function get_all() {
    //return $this->db->get('formvalidation')->row(); //object
    return $this->db->get('formvalidation')->row_array(); //array
} 

}
```